# Unexpected token

Tags: react-native

I'm working on react-native for. In the code below, I can't figure out what the unexpected token is.  Any ideas?

```
export default class connects extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header>
                    <Title>Header</Title>
                </Header>

                <Content>
                    // Your main content goes here
                </Content>

                <Footer>
                    <FooterTab>
                        <Button transparent>
                            <Icon name='ios-call' />
                        </Button>
                    </FooterTab>
                </Footer>
            </Container>
        );
    }
};
```

> (node:14026) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): SyntaxError: SyntaxError /home/samgitre/Mobile/Workspace/connects/index.android.js: Unexpected token (7:13)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message you're seeing.

Comment: You should try to change class name with `capitalize`.

Comment: This is the error I'm having : (node:14026) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): SyntaxError: SyntaxError /home/samgitre/Mobile/Workspace/connects/index.android.js: Unexpected token (7:13)      I have tried to capilize the class but still having same message.

Comment: And the code above are the codes inside the index.android.js filde

Answer (score 2):

In JSX, comments are inserted using a "javascript" comment:

```
 {/* Your main content goes here */}
```

Comment: This is correct, @SpencersAllen you aren't wrapping your JSX inline code with braces. This should be fairly evident in your IDE which should normally turn comments green/grey.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the response, but I still have the same error even after removing the whole comment. I don't really know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That `transparent` on `Button` is not valid. What you want is:

```
<Button color='transparent' />
```

Comment: Yes,  I'm using the  Native-base module for easy styling and icons,  that is how it is in the documentation (http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.13/components)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem when using the Anatomy example of Native-Base.
After many times spent to find the workaround, i have found the answer :)
You need to had this two lines in your index.android.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
```

.... Your class TEST1

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('test1', () => TEST1)
```